# Google Maps API: Adding letters to my markers on my google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, label

I'm trying to add a letter to my marker and then have multiple markers (14 to be accurate) with letters. l have so far done this without success. I'm a complete novice with code and google API.

Can you tell what code l need to add and where?

Below is my code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=....
  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GScaleControl());


    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var point = new GLatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
    map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));

    var point = new GLatLng(lat,ling);
    map.setCenter(point, 10);
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
```

}

```
   GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {
   var center = map.getCenter();
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = center.toString();
   });



    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat,ling), 7);

  }
}
//]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">
```

## Venue Location

Thanks

Comment: >>I'm trying to add a letter to my marker
 -- Are you trying to change the icon itself? I am not sure what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the code to add markers with alphabets. Run the loop for all the markers, index is each marker position

```
let letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + index),
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: this.map,
    position: latLongObj,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png",
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```

[Here is the list of map marker icons](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapicons/)

Answer (score 10):

Use the Charts API to generate markers:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html#pins

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. What's wrong with using the Charts API? Providing lettered markers is beyond the scope of the Maps API itself. If you want green ones, try http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/marker_greenA.png (replace A with the desired letter)

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to change the marker itself look at http://googlemapsmarkers.com - if you use their URL for your marker you can specify what the marker looks like:

http://googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/A/ff00ff/

Answer (score 4):

Use the `label` option when defining the marker object like this:

```
   markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointB,
        title: "point B",
        label: "B",
        map: map
    })
```

From the [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference):

> Type:  string|MarkerLabel Adds a label to the marker. The label can
>   either be a string, or a MarkerLabel object. Only the first character
>   of the string will be displayed.

```js
function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2750, 1.0870),
    pointC = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5379, 0.7138),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: pointA,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "AAA",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    }),
    markerC = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointC,
      title: "point C",
      label: "C",
      map: map
    });
}

initMap();
```

```css
html,
 body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #map-canvas {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

And here's the same [demo on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/dcvc99qz/)